# Magento 2 | How to put Button in Guest user Order and Account Information Page?

Tags: magento2, email, plugin

I need to edit email address of Guest Customer.

As form the picture:
[image]

I know it should be done by plugin but I want to know What is the right way
to find right method to override for putting button at this particular place and applying the functionality.